# Difficulty getting parameters passed in through a route to appear with the reddit appi in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display all of the threads from a series of subreddits when the user clicks on a list item throgh the use of routes and react. However, I'm having some issues getting this info to display. Here is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import AnimalPage from './AnimalPage'
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
const animals="/animals";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <h1>Animal threads</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink to=animals+"/cat">
                Cats
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to=animals+"/chicken">
                Chickens
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to=animals+"/cow">
                Cows
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to=animals+"/dog">
                Dogs
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink to=animals+"/pig">
                Pigs
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true} />
          <Route path=animals+"/:animal" component={AnimalPage}>
            <AnimalPage />
          </Route>
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

And here is where the reddit api is called:

```js
const API_URL = 'https://www.reddit.com';
export async function fetchThreads(animal) {
  let response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/r/${animal}.json`);
  return response.json();
}
```

And finally here is where the info is supposed to render, AnimalPage:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { fetchThreads } from './RedditApi';
import ThreadCard from './ThreadCard';
import Loading from './Loading';

export default class AnimalPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      threads: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    let threads = await fetchThreads(this.props.match.params.animal);
    this.setState({ threads:threads.data.children, loading: false });
  }
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="threads">
        {this.state.loading ? <Loading /> : this.state.threads.map((thread) => {
            return <ThreadCard thread={thread} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have misunderstood the concept of `Route` and `Link`.

The `Route` has to tell which component it is to render when encountering a certain route. Anything in the path with `:` in front of it is a variable. For eg. if you say:

```
<Route path="/animals/:animal" component={AnimalPage} />
```

will render the `AnimalPage` when URLs like `/animals/cat` or `/animals/dog` is taken. Remember that `:animal` is the name of the variable, any string can take it's place. `/animals` is a constant.

To lead to any of these pages, you will need a `Link` that says:

```
<NavLink to="/animals/cat">Cat</NavLink>
```

Now, you can access the variable ID inside the component `AnimalPage` with:

```
this.props.match.params.animal
```

[URL Parameters Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: Ok but now in AnimalPage when I write `let threads = await fetchThreads(this.props.match.params.animal);` it says this is undefined

Comment: @KyleVanHousen What have you provided as the `Route` path and what is the current URL?

Comment: Route Path is /animals/:animal, I fixed all of the nav links according to your instructions, and the url is http://localhost:3000/animals/:chicken

Comment: `Link` as it says should not have `:chicken`, just `chicken` is good enough. You have already declared the variable in `:animal`, chicken is just the value for it

Comment: So I should delete the : in the NavLink?

Comment: Because I did that and it says it's still undefined

Comment: @KyleVanHousen That should work, can you edit the question and add your current code so I can check

Comment: @KyleVanHousen As I mentioned in the answer, `/animals` should be a constant, if you would like the route to be `/dogs` or `/cats` then, `animals` should be a variable as well

Comment: @KyleVanHousen That's not right, are you familiar with how React works? If you want all routes to be `/animals/:animal` then it's right, but if you want it as `chickens/chicken` its not

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost here